# Android - setRequestedOrientation - Activity and views lifecycle

Tags: java, android, view, java-native-interface

I'm having some trouble with native code using JNI and I suspect that this is maybe due to a call to `setRequestedOrientation()`.

What happens to the activity when I call `setRequestedOrientation()`? Is it just restarted or is it entirely destroyed?

Also, what happens the to views? If in onCreate I have :

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    try
    {
        this.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE );

        setContentView( R.layout.activity_XXX );
        mTermScreenView = (TermScreenView) findViewById( R.id.termScreenView );
```

What happens to the View object? Is it recreated? Does it already exist when I call `findViewById()`? Is another View recreated after the screen gets rotated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you setRequestedOrientation() the view may be restarted. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)

> Change the desired orientation of this activity. If the activity is currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting the screen orientation, the screen will immediately be changed (possibly causing the activity to be restarted). Otherwise, this will be used the next time the activity is visible.

When you rotate your screen or change the orientation, by default android will destroy and recreate the view. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`SetRequestedOrientation` needs to be used with some care.  The statement that “The view may be restarted” needs some explanation.

The program will run through to completion – `Stop` in the Activity-lifecycle and then restart – loop back to `Start` in the Activity-lifecycle.

The first run through will be with the starting orientation (usually `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN`) and with the requested orientation (typically `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`).

So, for example:

```
static int i;
...
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
...
    i++;
...
dosomething(i);
```

Will run in landscape mode with `i == 2`.